# How to check if a class has a certain name?

Tags: javascript, class

Good afternoon!

I am building a simple reservation system for a cinema. I have a graphic depiction of the cinemas' available seats. There are 3 types of seats: The grey ones that cost 7 dollars, the yellow ones that cost 9 dollars and the red ones that cost 11 dollars.

I have given each different kind of seat a class: A for the 7 dollar ones, B for the 9 dollar ones and C for the 11 dollar ones. Each seat is a HTML button.

```
<body>


<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input id="1" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="2" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="3" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="4" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="5" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="6" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="7" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td><input id="8" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7)" /></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Now, what I want to do is run a function that checks which button with which class has been pressed, and thus which price the user should get.

So far, I have tried something like this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClass("A") === "A") {
    alert("i am an a");
} else {
    alert("i am something else");
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

-Robert

Comment: use document.getElementsByClassName instead of document.getElementsByClass

Comment: if (document.getElementsByClass("A") === "A") - This has no sense, you're trying to compare an array of HTML elements with a string.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I just tried something. In essence what I want to do is check what kind of class the button the user clicked on has, and go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.className` property to check class name of button clicked by user. `.getElementsByClassName` will return all elements which have class name set to "A". 

You can easily check that return type is `Array` :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("A")
if (elements.constructor == Array) {
   // elements is Array
   elements.forEach(function(element) {
       // element has className === "A"
   }
}
```

---

If you want to check button's class when user clicks it use something like:

```js
var myFunction = function (id, button) {
 if (button.className === "A") {
     alert("I'm A!");
 }
}
```

```html
<input id="1" class="A" type="button" onclick="myFunction(7, this)" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, sorry... what do you mean by "Array" in you last line? Should I just use "A" there?

Comment: Hmmm, I would have thought your code example would have worked, but unfortunately ALL buttons now give the "I am something else alert" when theyre clicked!

Comment: if (this.className === "A") 
      {
        alert("i am an a");
      } 
    else
    {
        alert("i am something else");
    } //this was my last attempt